# Can I use mod_rewrite with switch case

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website has 2 languages. When I change language, I want the URL to change as well, similar to this:

```
www.domain.com
```

changing to this:

```
www.domain.com/th
```

and this:

```
www.domain.com/en
```

My php:

**config.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(empty($_SESSION['language'])){
    $_SESSION['language'] = "th";
}

if ($_SESSION['language'] == "th") {
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/language/th.php";
} else {
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/language/en.php";
}

$base_url = "/";

function lang($th, $en) {
    if ($_SESSION['language'] == "th") {
        return $th;
    } else {
        return $en;
    }
}
```

**lang.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

switch ($_POST["lang"]) {
    case "th":
        $_SESSION['language'] = "th";
        echo json_encode("complete");
        break;

    case "en":
        $_SESSION['language'] = "en";

        echo json_encode("complete");
        break;

    default :
        break;
}
?>
```

**links to change language**

```
<li><a href="javascript:lang('th');" <?= $_SESSION['language'] == "th" ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?> >TH</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:lang('en');" <?= $_SESSION['language'] == "en" ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?> >EN</a></li>
```

Can I use .htaccess to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't acceess the PHP session from `.htaccess`. But you could use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite every request to your config.php.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Only for non-existing directories, files or symlinks
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* config.php [L]
</IfModule>
```